# Possible bug in FF (51.0.1) - Video with inline rotation at 70deg do not render video control properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I found a possible bug in Firefox 51.0.1 32 bit on Windows 10.
The issue is noticeable when a video has applied transformation rotateZ of 70deg inline.
As you can see from the image the video controller do not match video length dimension.
The issue is not reproducible if the rotation is setup at 60 deg.

I would like to know:

- Do you know a work around to this issue?
- What could cause the problem?

[image]

```js
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
            let btn = document.getElementById('button');
            let target = document.getElementById('target');
            let rotation = 70;
            btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
                rotation += 10;
                target.style.transform = `rotateZ(${rotation}deg)`;
            });

        });
```

```html
    <video id="target" controls style="width: 560px; height: 320px; transform: rotateZ(70deg)">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <button id="button">Click me to rotate video</button>
```

Comment: Interesting find. One possible workaround could be to hide the default controls and add your own instead. Maybe those would rotate along properly?

Comment: @domdom thanks for your comment, yes could be an idea. But I would prefer using the native control element if possible.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that this bug is present on Firefox branch 51 (stable one) but not present on Firefox Developer edition at branch 53 version 53.0a2 (2017-03-06) (32-bit).

As I could not find any reference in their bug tracking system I created a dedicated ticket:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1344689